# Laravel spark project create issues

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

[image]

Please help me solve this issue.Everything is fine. Its ubuntu. The spark create new project gives this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to do a

source ~/.bashrc

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation:

`Finally, you are ready to run the spark:install command:`

This is of course using a different installation method to the binary they supply. In fact they recommend other methods as well such as setting up a new Laravel project and adding Spark as a dependency:

https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.0/installation#installation-via-composer

running:

`php artisan spark:install --force`

once you have followed their installation steps from the above link (correct as of time of writing).

I've personally used the latter method and never had a problem with it. Please give it a go and let us know the results.